# wicked-good-xpath for chrome extension content page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xpath, google-chrome-extension, wicked-good-xpath

How can I make the [wicked-good-xpath](https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/downloads/list) library available to a chrome extension's content page?

I've tried putting it in the manifest.json file but wgxpath.install() fails. In the example below, alert.js fires it's alert and injected.js runs and is available in the source tab. No WGXPath though.

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
      "js"      : ["res/js/alert.js", "res/js/wgxpath.install.js", "injected.js" ],
      "run_at"  : "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put it into your view html body? :)

Comment: @Lashus: It is a content script. There is no view - it applies to all URLs.

Comment: No idea then, sorry. My guess would be that because evaluate is a security violation it is not executed.  http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sandboxingEval.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs for **[Wicked-Good-XPath](https://code.google.com/p/wicked-good-xpath/)**, `wgxpath.install()` ensures that the XPAth evaluation function *"...is defined on the window object."*.

According to the docs for Chrome extension **[Content Scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)**, the content scripts "live" in an isolated world (JS context) and as far as the `window` object properties are concerned:

*"Each isolated world sees its own version of the object. Assigning to the object affects your independent copy of the object."*

---

I haven't tried it myself, but most probably you need to have Wicket-Good-XPath in the JS context of the web-page (not the content script), so you should have your content script add a `script` element, with a `src` pointing to the *wgxpath.install.js* file and then execute `wgxpath.install()` in the JS context of the web-page.
Additionally, you need to add the *wgxpath.install.js* file to your extension's **[`web_accessible_resources`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources.html)**.

Sample code:

**In *manifest.json*:**

```
...
"content_scripts": [{
    ...
    "js": ["res/js/alert.js", "injected.js"],
    ...
}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["/res/js/wgxpath.install.js"]
```

**In *injected.js*:**

```
/* "Embed" `wgxpath.install.js` into the web-page */
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = chrome.extension.getURL("/res/js/wgxpath.install.js");
document.body.appendChild(script);

/* "Install" Wicked-Good-XPath into the web-pages context */
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.textContent = "wgxpath.install();";
document.body.appendChild(script);
/*Optionaly*/script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

<sub>Depending on how you want to use Wicked-Good-XPath, you will probably need to inject more code into the web-page's JS context (or device a way to communicate between the two JS contexts).</sub>

---

BTW, **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script#answer-9517879)** is a very good reference of the several ways you can inject code or content scripts into a web-page, using a Chrome extension.

Comment: Excellent answer, injection technique works well thank you. Sadly now getting NotSupportedError for all xpaths, but I suspect that's for a separate question.